# override of type signature from abstract class

Tags: f#, overriding, abstract-class

I have the following class definition for a generic filter.
In line with functional principles, I would like to have a function that updates the filter and returns a new object of Filter type. This would allow me to operate updates without resolving to mutability

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type Filter<'T, 'a> (filterState: 'T) =
    let FilterState = filterState
    abstract member Update: 'a -> Filter<'T, 'a>
    abstract member GetState: unit -> 'T
```

I have then a specialized implementation:

```
type LKF (filterState: GenericMatrix, a: GenericMatrix, p: GenericMatrix, q: GenericMatrix, r: GenericMatrix, h: GenericMatrix) =
    inherit Filter<GenericMatrix, GenericMatrix> (filterState)
    let A = a
    let P = p
    let Q = q
    let R = r
    let H = h

    override this.Update(obsVector: GenericMatrix) =
        [... do calculations here] 
        new LKF(newx, A, P, Q, R, H)        

    override this.GetState() =
        filterState
```

The issue is that the compiler flags `new LKF(newx, A, P, Q, R, H)` as an error because it was expecting a return value of type `Filter<'T, 'a>`, according to the type signature in the abstract class, but it gets an `LKF` instead. I thought it should be fine because `LKF` is a subtype of `Filter<'T, 'a>`, but I am wrong.

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# doesn't cast/convert/coerce implicitly (though [flexible types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd233198.aspx) exist). You have to cast it explicitly:

```
 new LKF(newx, A, P, Q, R, H) :> Filter<_, _>
```

Note `:>` operator: this it's so called static cast and it is performed at compile time.

**UPDATE**

It can be even simpler as suggested in the comments `new LKF(newx, A, P, Q, R, H) :> _`

Comment: Thanks. How would you use flexible types in this case? I have tried: `abstract member Update: 'a -> #Filter<'T, 'a>` but this is prob. not the way it works..

Comment: @EugeneFotin I'm not near a computer, but wouldn't `:> _` also work in this case?

Comment: Don't forget about `upcast`.